# Is this only definition?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

> If $u$   is  twice differentiable and $\Omega$ a domain  and $\Delta$ the Laplace operator then
>   $$ -\Delta u \in C(\Omega) \Rightarrow u \in C^2(\Omega)  $$

I think it is only definition .
Thanks for your answer .

Comment: For next time, please don't put large amounts of text in-between dollar signs.

Comment: sorry , I am new here and not good at writing in latex

Comment: The *definition* of $u\in C^2(\Omega)$ is that, for all $i,j$, $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}$ is continuous on $\Omega$. The *definition* of $-\Delta u\in C(\Omega)$ is that $-\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1^2}-\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2^2}-\cdots- \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_n^2}$ is continuous on $\Omega$. So you can see for yourself how far the definitions bring you to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I think  then the other direction holds too .